# Where does my friend live?

Tags: knowledge, geography

When I asked my friend who lives overseas where he lives, he gave me a code:

MBOD, DONE, ETNA, LAYS, ANMA, PINE, ILAN, PORE, RUNE, ESTE

The country where he lives is not included in the code, where he is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly your friend lives in:

> **LAOS**

The code consists of:

> 4-letter fragments that can be found within the names of 10 of the 11 countries traditionally classed as being in [Southeast Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeast_Asia):
>
>  CA**MBOD**IA, IN**DONE**SIA, VI**ETNA**M, MA**LAYS**IA, MY**ANMA**R, PHILIP**PINE**S, THA**ILAN**D, SINGA**PORE**, B**RUNE**I, TIMOR-L**ESTE**.
>
>  The eleventh country that usually completes this list is **LAOS**, which cannot be included in the coded list without giving away its identity since it is only 4 letters long!

Comment: Wow! How fast you are to figure out the answer!

Comment: @00xxqhxx00 Your question hooked me right in :) I'm an unashamed sucker for geography trivia!